# POST request works, DELETE request does not

Tags: java, http, sha256, hmac

I have the following code I created which works to open a trade on the Phemex API via HMAC-SHA256 encrypted request signature. It needs to be a POST request.

```
public void openTradeByLimit(double size, double price, int id) throws Exception {
        String path = "/orders";
        String query = "";
        String body = "";
        if(size>0){
            body = "{\"symbol\":\"uBTCUSD\", \"clOrdID\":" + id + ",\"side\":\"Buy\",\"orderQty\":" + size + ",\"ordType\":\"Limit\",\"priceEp\":" + price*10000 +  ",\"reduceOnly\":false,\"timeInForce\":\"GoodTillCancel\"}"; //json parsed body
        } else {
            body = "{\"symbol\":\"uBTCUSD\", \"clOrdID\":" + id + ",\"side\":\"Sell\",\"orderQty\":" + Math.abs(size) + ",\"ordType\":\"Limit\",\"priceEp\":" + price*10000 +  ",\"reduceOnly\":false,\"timeInForce\":\"GoodTillCancel\"}"; //json parsed body
        }
        String ts = String.valueOf((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
        int expiry = Integer.parseInt(ts) + 600; //600 second expiry from current unix epoch time

        String requestSignature = HashString.getRequestSignature(path, query, expiry, body, PHEMEX_SECRET);

        String accessToken = PHEMEX_KEY;

        String requestExpiry = String.valueOf(expiry);

        URL url = new URL ("https://api.phemex.com/orders");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        connection.setRequestProperty("x-phemex-request-expiry", requestExpiry);
        connection.setRequestProperty("x-phemex-request-signature", requestSignature);
        connection.setRequestProperty("x-phemex-access-token", accessToken);

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        connection.connect();

        try(OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()){
            byte[] input = body.getBytes("utf-8");
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
        }


        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String responseLine = null;

            while((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                response.append(responseLine.trim());
            }

            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }


    }
```

This code works fine, and I am confident that the helper methods of HashString work correctly given they are provided the proper path, query, and body.

For reference, this call needs the following fields in the body: symbol, clOrderId, side, orderQty, ordType, priceEp, reduceOnly, timeInForce, and GoodTillCancel. For more reference visit https://github.com/phemex/phemex-api-docs/blob/master/Public-Contract-API-en.md#signatureexample3

However, when I replace the `connection.setRequestMethod("POST");` to         `connection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");`, delete the body, and add in the path `?symbol=uBTCUSD'`, I am doing the wrong API call. The request I need to send is
`DELETE /orders/all?symbol=<symbol>`

Since it is a DELETE request, if I am not mistaken the body should be empty.

For more reference, please visit https://github.com/phemex/phemex-api-docs/blob/master/Public-Contract-API-en.md#cancelall

I am using the following code, which I am having trouble debugging.

```
public void cancelAllOrders() throws Exception {
        String path = "/orders/all";
        String query = "?symbols=uBTCUSD";
        String body = ""; //json parsed body

        String ts = String.valueOf((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
        int expiry = Integer.parseInt(ts) + 600; //600 second expiry from current unix epoch time

        String requestSignature = HashString.getRequestSignature(path, query, expiry, body, PHEMEX_SECRET);

        String accessToken = PHEMEX_KEY;

        String requestExpiry = String.valueOf(expiry);

        URL url = new URL ("https://api.phemex.com/orders/all");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        connection.setRequestProperty("x-phemex-request-expiry", requestExpiry);
        connection.setRequestProperty("x-phemex-request-signature", requestSignature);
        connection.setRequestProperty("x-phemex-access-token", accessToken);

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        connection.connect();

        try(OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()){
            byte[] input = body.getBytes("utf-8");
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
        }


        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String responseLine = null;

            while((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                response.append(responseLine.trim());
            }

            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }


    }
```

In addition, here is the HashString class in case I am doing something incorrect which works for a body but not for a path.

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class HashString {

    private static final String HMAC_SHA256 = "HmacSHA256";

    public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            formatter.format("%02x", b);
        }
        return formatter.toString();
    }

    public static String calculateHMAC(String data, String key) throws SignatureException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException
    {
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA256);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256);
        mac.init(secretKeySpec);
        return toHexString(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes()));
    }

    // returns valid request signature needed for Phemex authentication header 'x-phemex-request-signature'
    public static String getRequestSignature(String Path, String Query, int expiry, String body, String secret){
        String secretKey = secret;
        String signatureString = Path + Query + expiry + body;

        String hmac = "";
        try {
            hmac = calculateHMAC(signatureString, secretKey);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            hmac = "-1";
            System.out.println("Could not create HMAC SHA256!");
        }

        return hmac;
    }

    public HashString(){
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

    }

}
```

Tried replacing the type of request to DELETE from POST and updating the path, but the request signature is invalid.

Comment: `setDoOutput()` sets the request method to POST. See the Javadoc. You need to do it *before* setting the request method.